# how to launch spark-job.py using spark-submit after kafka producer started

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-kafka

I have 3 files - kafka producer.py, consumer.py and spark-job.py. I dont know how to start spark file to make it process a stream of generated data coming from kafka.

- start zookeeper server in 1st terminal:

  .\bin\windows\zookeeper-start.bat .\config\zookeeper.properties
- then start kafka-server in 2nd separate terminal:

  .\bin\windows\kafka-server-start.bat .\config\server.properties

Then in 2 separate terminals I start a producer.py and consumer.py.

producer kafka file just generates some dictionary of data:

{branch, currency, amount}

and produces it to kafka cluster every 5 sec or so.

```
from json import dumps
from time import sleep
from numpy.random import choice, randint
from kafka import KafkaProducer

def get_random_value():
    new_dict = {}
    branch_list = ["Almaty", "Astana", "Taraz", "Semei"]
    currency_list = ["KZT", "RUB", "GBP", "USD"]

    new_dict['currency'] = choice(currency_list)
    new_dict['amount'] = randint(1, 100)
    new_dict['branch'] = choice(branch_list)
    # print(new_dict)
    return new_dict


if __name__ == "__main__":
    producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=['127.0.0.1:9092'],
                             value_serializer=lambda x: dumps(x).encode('utf-8'),
                             compression_type='gzip')
    topic_name = 'transaction'

    while True:
        for _ in range(100):
            data = get_random_value()
            try:
                message = producer.send(topic=topic_name, value=data)
                record_data = message.get(timeout=10)
                print('data: {}, offset: {}' \
                      .format(data, record_data.offset))
                #print(data)
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
            finally:
                producer.flush()
        sleep(5)
    producer.close()
```

consumer just prints that dict once it comes:

```
from kafka import KafkaConsumer
import json

consumer = KafkaConsumer('transaction',bootstrap_servers=['127.0.0.1:9092'])

print("start consuming")
for message in consumer:
    aa = json.loads(message.value.decode())
    print("currency: %s, amount: %d, branch: %s" %(aa['currency'], aa['amount'], aa['branch']))
```

producer,consumer works - outputs to terminal simultaneously.

[image: kk]
But once these 2 are working, i need to start spark-job.

Spark-job.py listens to the localhost:9092(where kafka also sits) and simply writes incoming data to a db.

```
import sys
import os
import shutil

from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
from pyspark.sql import Row, SparkSession
from pyspark.streaming.kafka import KafkaUtils
import json

outputPath = 'C:/Users/Admin/Downloads/madi_kafka/logs/checkpoints01'

def get_sql_query():
    strSQL = 'select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp()) as curr_time,t.branch as city,t.currency as currency,sum(amount) as amount from exchanges_stream t'
    return strSQL
# -------------------------------------------------
# Lazily instantiated global instance of SparkSession
# -------------------------------------------------
def getSparkSessionInstance(sparkConf):
    if ('sparkSessionSingletonInstance' not in globals()):
        globals()['sparkSessionSingletonInstance'] = SparkSession \
            .builder \
            .config(conf=sparkConf) \
            .getOrCreate()
    return globals()['sparkSessionSingletonInstance']
# -------------------------------------------------
# What I want to do per each RDD...
# -------------------------------------------------
def process(time, rdd):
    print("===========-----> %s <-----===========" % str(time))
    try:
        spark = getSparkSessionInstance(rdd.context.getConf())
        rowRdd = rdd.map(lambda w: Row(city=w['branch'],
                                       currency=w['currency'],
                                       amount=w['amount']))

        testDataFrame = spark.createDataFrame(rowRdd)

        testDataFrame.createOrReplaceTempView("exchanges_stream")

        sql_query = get_sql_query()
        testResultDataFrame = spark.sql(sql_query)
        testResultDataFrame.show(n=5)

        # Insert into DB
        try:
            testResultDataFrame.write \
                .format("jdbc") \
                .mode("append") \
                .option("driver", 'org.postgresql.Driver') \
                .option("url", "jdbc:postgresql://xxx") \
                .option("dbtable", "transaction_flow") \
                .option("user", "habr") \
                .option("password", "habr12345") \
                .save()
            
            print('DB write succesfull !')
        except Exception as e:
            print("-->Error with DB working!", e)

    except Exception as e:
        print("--> Error!", e)


# -------------------------------------------------
# General function
# -------------------------------------------------
def createContext():
    sc = SparkContext(appName="PythonStreamingKafkaTransaction")
    sc.setLogLevel("ERROR")

    ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 10)#  2

    broker_list, topic = sys.argv[1:]

    try:
        directKafkaStream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc,
                                                          [topic],
                                                          {"metadata.broker.list": broker_list})
    except:
        raise ConnectionError("Kafka error: Connection refused: \
                            broker_list={} topic={}".format(broker_list, topic))

    parsed_lines = directKafkaStream.map(lambda v: json.loads(v[1]))

    # RDD handling
    parsed_lines.foreachRDD(process)

    return ssc

if __name__ == "__main__":

    if len(sys.argv) != 3:
        print("Usage: spark_job.py <zk> <topic>", file=sys.stderr)
        exit(-1)

print("--> Creating new context")
if os.path.exists(outputPath):
    shutil.rmtree('outputPath')

ssc = StreamingContext.getOrCreate(outputPath, lambda: createContext())
ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()
```

I dont know how to launch spark-job.py.

while producer keeps generating msgs, i try to launch

```
spark-submit \
--packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-8_2.11:2.0.2,\
org.postgresql:postgresql:9.4.1207 \
spark_job.py localhost:9092 transaction
```

this gives:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Cannot load main class from JAR org.postgresql:postgresql:9.4.1207 with URI org.postgresql. Please specify a class through --class.
```

If I try to launch this cmd:

```
python.exe .\spark_job.py 127.0.0.1:2181 transaction
```

it does launch and creates new context, but still cant find some files:

```
--> Creating new context
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
20/07/25 06:12:46 WARN Checkpoint: Checkpoint directory C:/Users/Admin/Downloads/madi_kafka/logs/checkpoints01 does not exist

________________________________________________________________________________________________

  Spark Streaming's Kafka libraries not found in class path. Try one of the following.

  1. Include the Kafka library and its dependencies with in the
     spark-submit command as

     $ bin/spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-8:2.4.6 ...

  2. Download the JAR of the artifact from Maven Central http://search.maven.org/,
     Group Id = org.apache.spark, Artifact Id = spark-streaming-kafka-0-8-assembly, Version = 2.4.6.
     Then, include the jar in the spark-submit command as

     $ bin/spark-submit --jars <spark-streaming-kafka-0-8-assembly.jar> ...

________________________________________________________________________________________________


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\spark_job.py", line 88, in createContext
    {"metadata.broker.list": broker_list})
  File "C:\python37\lib\site-packages\pyspark\streaming\kafka.py", line 138, in createDirectStream
    helper = KafkaUtils._get_helper(ssc._sc)
  File "C:\python37\lib\site-packages\pyspark\streaming\kafka.py", line 217, in _get_helper
    return sc._jvm.org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtilsPythonHelper()
TypeError: 'JavaPackage' object is not callable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\spark_job.py", line 114, in <module>
    ssc = StreamingContext.getOrCreate(outputPath, lambda: createContext())
  File "C:\python37\lib\site-packages\pyspark\streaming\context.py", line 107, in getOrCreate
    ssc = setupFunc()
  File ".\spark_job.py", line 114, in <lambda>
    ssc = StreamingContext.getOrCreate(outputPath, lambda: createContext())
  File ".\spark_job.py", line 91, in createContext
    broker_list={} topic={}".format(broker_list, topic))
ConnectionError: Kafka error: Connection refused:                             broker_list=127.0.0.1:2181 topic=transaction
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`--packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-8_2.11:2.0.2` is correct

Assuming

1. You are using Spark 2.0.2 and have installed Scala 2.11 (both of which are old, and out of date), plus Spark *Structured* Streaming is the new hotness (packaged as `spark-sql-kafka`)... Would like to point out: Your error says you have Spark **2.4.6**, where Spark Streaming is deprecated, and SQL-Kafka package would save you the headache of converting RDD into Dataframes

First error is related to Postgres classes missing. As answered before, I strongly advise not using Spark when [Kafka Connect exists for this very purpose](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-jdbc/sink-connector/index.html), but to fix, you need to add postgres JARs to the packages list (or more accurately, the Spark classpath)

Second error is becuase you are now missing the `--packages` argument via the environment variable called `PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS`

```
os.environ["PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS"] = "--packages <kafka>"

sc = get_context()
```

Comment: thx u, yes, i have spark 2.4.6, Scala version 2.11.12 and i made it work with this long command: spark-submit --jars spark-streaming-kafka-assembly_2.11-1.6.3.jar --class spark-streaming-kafka-0-8_2.11-2.4.6.jar ./spark_job.py 127.0.0.1:9092 transaction

Comment: i installed those jars files but then i have next bug , but it's for another question.

Comment: Once again, that 1.6.3 is incorrect. Please use the correct Spark version for all Spark related JARs

Comment: thx for pointing out - 1.6.3 is the LATEST available if you check this link on maven https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-streaming-kafka-assembly

Comment: Because it was deprecated https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-sql-kafka-0-10

Comment: @Onecriket , yes i did download spark-streaming-kafka-0-8-assembly_2.11-2.4.6.jar and still no result, cant even launch simple example with streaming context

Comment: could u pls help?

Comment: My suggestion still stands to refractor to use Structured Streaming if you must use Spark for some reason. I don't know Streaming API